# How to get iframe images to print as part of full document in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, printing

I have two IFRAMEs.  Each IFRAME is loaded dynamically as the result of submitting a FORM.  The result of each FORM submit is a dynamically generated jpeg image (Content-type: image/jpeg).  The following page displays correctly (you can see both images).  If you try to print this page in IE however, you just get an outline of the images, but not the actual images.  It prints correctly in Safari and Chrome.  How can you get the IFRAME images to print along with the rest of the document in IE?
I am using IE 9.0.8112.16421.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>View Image</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="top.document.Form1.submit();top.docment.Form2.submit();">
<FORM NAME=Form1 ACTION="URL" METHOD=POST Target=Img1>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=ID VALUE=123>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=Cmd VALUE=DispImage1>
</FORM>
<FORM NAME=Form2 ACTION="URL" METHOD=POST Target=Img2>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=ID VALUE=345>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=Cmd VALUE=DispImage2>
</FORM>
<IFRAME NAME=Img1 SRC=Javascript:'' WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=250 FRAMEBORDER=0 SCROLLING=no>
</IFRAME><BR>
<IFRAME NAME=Img2 SRC=Javascript:'' WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=250 FRAMEBORDER=0 SCROLLING=no>
</IFRAME>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```